# JQ, how to count depending on conditions?

Tags: json, linux, bash, debian, jq

Using jq, I need to **get the count** within an array depending on two criterias: it MUST have `status === 'skipped' && ref.includes(version)`

```
[
  {
    "id": 15484,
    "sha": "52606c8da57984d1243f436e5d12e275db29a6e0",
    "ref": "v1.4.15",
    "status": "canceled"
  },
  {
    "id": 15483,
    "sha": "52606c8da57984d1243f436e5d12e275db29a6e0",
    "ref": "v1.4.15",
    "status": "canceled"
  },
  {
    "id": 15482,
    "sha": "1b4ccc1dc17e9b8ddb24550c5566d2be6b03465e",
    "ref": "dev",
    "status": "success"
  },
  {
    "id": 15481,
    "sha": "5b6ec939739c5a1513634f3b58bf96522917571d",
    "ref": "dev",
    "status": "failed"
  },
  {
    "id": 15480,
    "sha": "ec18d46f491a4645c68388df91fc41455b421e71",
    "ref": "dev",
    "status": "failed"
  },
  {
    "id": 15479,
    "sha": "dd83a6d6e58cc5114aed8016341ab3c5b3ebb702",
    "ref": "dev",
    "status": "failed"
  },
  {
    "id": 15478,
    "sha": "18ccaf4bc37bf65470b2c6ddaa69e5b4018354a7",
    "ref": "dev",
    "status": "success"
  },
  {
    "id": 15477,
    "sha": "f90900d733bce2be3d9ba9db25f8b51296bc6f3f",
    "ref": "dev",
    "status": "failed"
  },
  {
    "id": 15476,
    "sha": "3cf0431a161e6c9ca90e8248af7b4ec39c54bfb1",
    "ref": "dev",
    "status": "failed"
  },
  {
    "id": 15285,
    "sha": "d24b46edc75d8f7308dbef37d7b27625ef70c845",
    "ref": "dev",
    "status": "success"
  },
  {
    "id": 15265,
    "sha": "52606c8da57984d1243f436e5d12e275db29a6e0",
    "ref": "v1.4.15",
    "status": "success"
  },
  {
    "id": 15264,
    "sha": "9a15f8d4c950047f88c642abda506110b9b0bbd7",
    "ref": "v1.4.15-static",
    "status": "skipped"
  },
  {
    "id": 15263,
    "sha": "9a15f8d4c950047f88c642abda506110b9b0bbd7",
    "ref": "v1.4.15-static",
    "status": "skipped"
  },
  {
    "id": 15262,
    "sha": "76451d2401001c4c51b9800d3cdf62e4cdcc86ba",
    "ref": "v1.4.15-no-js",
    "status": "skipped"
  },
  {
    "id": 15261,
    "sha": "76451d2401001c4c51b9800d3cdf62e4cdcc86ba",
    "ref": "v1.4.15-no-js",
    "status": "skipped"
  },
  {
    "id": 15260,
    "sha": "515cd1b00062e9cbce05420036f5ecc7a898a4bd",
    "ref": "v1.4.15-cli",
    "status": "skipped"
  },
  {
    "id": 15259,
    "sha": "515cd1b00062e9cbce05420036f5ecc7a898a4bd",
    "ref": "v1.4.15-cli",
    "status": "skipped"
  },
  {
    "id": 15258,
    "sha": "b67acd3082da795f022fafc304d267d3afd6b736",
    "ref": "v1.4.15-node",
    "status": "skipped"
  },
  {
    "id": 15257,
    "sha": "b67acd3082da795f022fafc304d267d3afd6b736",
    "ref": "v1.4.15-node",
    "status": "skipped"
  },
  {
    "id": 15256,
    "sha": "4da4a788a85d82527ea568fed4f03da193842a80",
    "ref": "v1.4.15-bs-redux-saga-router-dom-intl",
    "status": "skipped"
  }
]
```

We also like to use environment variable for the query :

- `status=skipped`
- `ref=v1.4.15`

This work but without environment variable options:

```
cat test.json | jq '[.[] | select(.status=="skipped") | select(.ref | startswith("v1.4.15"))] | length'
```

How is this possible?

### Answer:

```
status=skipped; ref=v1.4.15; cat test.json | jq --arg REF "$ref" --arg STATUS "$status" -r '[.[] | select(.status==$STATUS) | select(.ref | startswith($REF))] | length'
```

Comment: What does `ref.includes(version)` mean? That doesn't look like jq syntax (and I think three ='s is an error too)

Comment: And by count do you mean the number of matching elements of the array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `length()` function at the end of the filter, after putting the objects list into an array

```
jq '[.[] | select(.status == "skipped") | select(.ref | test("1\\.4\\.15"))] | length'
```

but for just returning the objects leave out the logic to get the length

```
jq '[.[] | select(.status == "skipped") | select(.ref | test("1\\.4\\.15"))]'
```

The [`test()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example80) is a more powerful way to match your regex with JSON strings. The `startswith()` or `endswith()` can't match strings if they are in the middle.

Using variables,

```
ref="1\.4\.15"
jq --arg status "$status" --arg ref "$ref" \
    '[.[] | select(.status == $status) | select(.ref | test($ref))]|length' json
```

Comment: I just cannot disagree. Take this positive feedback and accepted answer.

Comment: Just to comment on the use of regexes, if you're going to use it, you need to make sure you escape characters that need escaping. Those periods will match anything so it may include the wrong items.

Answer (score 4):

By using map(select(...) or equivalent, you could use `length`, but it is generally more efficient to use a generic counting function, such as:

```
def sigma(s): reduce s as $s (null; .+$s);

sigma(.[] | select(.status=="skipped" and (.ref | startswith("v1.4.15") )) | 1)
```

### Using shell and environment variables

Using shell and environment variables is covered in the jq manual, but in brief, one way to pass in string values is using the command-line option `--arg`, e.g. along the lines of:

```
jq --arg status "$status" --arg ref "$ref" -f program.jq test.json
```

Comment: It look like jq but it also look like sigma, it does not use environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

I know `jq` is popular around here, but may I suggest `xidel`? See http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html.
Just like `jq` it's a JSON interpreter, but besides JSONiq you can also use XPath/Xquery functions to do all sorts of cool stuff.

This would list all objects with the 2 criteria:

```
xidel -s test.json -e '$json()[status="skipped" and starts-with(ref,"v1.4.15")]'
```

To count them, simply enclose the query with the `count()` function:

```
xidel -s test.json -e 'count($json()[status="skipped" and starts-with(ref,"v1.4.15")])'
```

This returns `9`.

With variables:

```
status=skipped
ref=v1.4.15

xidel -s test.json -e 'count($json()[status="'$status'" and starts-with(ref,"'$ref'")])'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, this would be an equivalent JSONiq query:

```
let $a := [
   (: copy-paste the entire array here in plain JSON syntax --
      omitted for the sake of brevity :)
]
return count(
   for $obj in $a[]
   where $obj.status eq "skipped"
         and
         matches($obj.ref, "ˆv")
   return $obj
)
```